# Using the POST Method for Batch Geocoding with ArcGIS Server REST API?

Tags: python, rest, post, geocoding, arcgis-server

I'm trying to hit my geocoding server's REST API:

[https://locator.stanford.edu/arcgis/rest/services/geocode/USA_StreetAddress/GeocodeServer] (ArcGIS Server 10.6.1)

...using the POST method (which, BTW, could use an example or two, there only seems to be this VERY brief "note" on WHEN to use POST, not HOW: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-geocode-addresses.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_351DE4FD98FE44958C8194EC5A7BEF7D).

I'm trying to use requests.post(), and I think I've managed to get the token accepted, etc..., but I keep getting a 400 error.

Based upon previous experience, this means something about the formatting of the data is bad, but I've cut-&-pasted directly from the Esri support site, this test pair.

```py
# import the requests library
import requests

# Multiple address records
addresses={ 
 "records": [
 {
 "attributes": {
 "OBJECTID": 1,
 "Street": "380 New York St.",
 "City": "Redlands",
 "Region": "CA",
 "ZIP": "92373"
 }
 },
 {
 "attributes": {
 "OBJECTID": 2,
 "Street": "1 World Way",
 "City": "Los Angeles",
 "Region": "CA",
 "ZIP": "90045"
 }
 }
 ]
}

# Parameters
# Geocoder endpoint
URL = 'https://locator.stanford.edu/arcgis/rest/services/geocode/USA_StreetAddress/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses?'
# token from locator.stanford.edu/arcgis/tokens
mytoken = <GeneratedToken>
# output spatial reference id 
outsrid = 4326
# output format
format = 'pjson'
# params data to be sent to api 
params ={'outSR':outsrid,'f':format,'token':mytoken}

# Use POST to batch geocode
r = requests.post(url=URL, data=addresses, params=params)

print(r.json())
print(r.text)
```

Here's what I consistently get:

```
{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Unable to complete operation.', 'details': []}}
```

Comment: in case anyone wants to try hitting a service that _isnt_ password protected: http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Locators/SanDiego/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to play around with this for longer than I'd like to admit, but the trick (I guess) is to use the correct request header *and* convert the raw addresses to a JSON string using `json.dumps()`.

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Locators/SanDiego/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses'
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
addresses = json.dumps({ 'records': [{ 'attributes': { 'OBJECTID': 1, 'SingleLine': '2920 Zoo Dr' }}] })

r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = { 'addresses': addresses, 'f':'json'})

print(r.text)
```

Comment: This was it! @Esri needs to doc their REST API better.

Comment: full disclosure, the way I figured this out was by using Charles/Fiddler to compare failing python requests with a successful request made directly in the browser.

besides the server being a little picky with regard to the header the other bit is just generic python stuff, not something 'Esri' specific. years ago pat mentioned to me that he'd like to include code snippets in several languages for each REST doc page, but it'd be tough to please everyone. for example, other folks would want to see a 2.x snippet.

Comment: @Esri should also return (or at least log) better error messages than 'unable to complete', please include the 'why'